# JQuery UI draggable is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a div draggable and but when i add the div with Jquery prepend
statement draggable is not working.

here is my Code :

```
var myString = '<div class="artimg ui-widget-content"><img id="artimg" src="' + imgname + '" width="150" height="150"></div>';
$('.front-style').prepend(myString);
```

Dragabble code :

```
$(function() {
    $("#artimg").draggable();
});
```

Comment: You need to ensure the element is in the DOM *before* you instantiate the `draggable()` plugin on it.

Comment: Use `prepend()` and then call `draggable()`

Comment: Thank you it is working now

Answer (score 0):

You have to first inject the desired element to the page before calling `.draggable()` on it, like so:

```
var $img = $('<img id="artimg" src="' + imgname + '" width="150" height="150">');
var $wrapper = $('<div />').addClass("artimg ui-widget-content")
                           .append($img);
$('.front-style').prepend($wrapper);

$img.draggable();
```